# running python via mac ports

Tags: macos, python, osx-leopard, macports, python3

I have installed python via mac ports, using:

```
sudo port install python33
```

I then did:

```
sudo port select --set python python33
```

and got:

```
Selecting 'python33' for 'python' succeeded. 'python33' is now active.
```

However when I do `which python` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

and for `which python3` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin/python3
```

What have I done wrong?

When I do: `port select --list python`

I get:

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python33 (active)
```

When I do `type -a python`, I get:

```
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /opt/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
```

When I type: echo $PATH, I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

which looks on the path to find the first python that it can find. port select changes /opt/local/bin/python to call the chosen python. For this to work /opt/local/bin has to be on the path before any other directory that contains python.

In your case you have `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin` before `/opt/local/bin`.

You need to clean up your path. I would suggest starting from scratch and only adding directories that you know and understand. You seem to have installed python in many ways and also have installed fink and macports. I would only use one of the package managers and remove all the explicit pythons from the path.